# detect the win gui process that starts in windows using c#?ManagementEventWatcher

Tags: c#, user-interface, managementeventwatcher

how to detect the process that have an interface like chrome , skype , torrent , explorer etc and get this process id , name , title , and parent id so what i did is that i get all the process list running in windows but i want to get the process name when it starts and process must have an interface or GUI look

here is  function i want to start watcher when it detects the GUI process it works recursively but i want to handle it event based and only GUI check

```
public  void callme() {


    WqlEventQuery query =
          new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent",
          new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),
          "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");


}
```

i have win form and i also want windows title in its options options and parent id