# How to get the parent process id and windows title? c#

Tags: c#, windows-services, win32-process

Here is how I'm getting the *"process created event"* from:

[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject WaitForNextEvent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventwatcher.waitfornextevent)

```
ManagementBaseObject e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
```

I require the:

1. Window Title
2. Caption *(editor's note: I think Window Title and Caption are the same)*
3. Session Id
4. Process Id
5. Process Id (Parent)

What I have right now:

```
ManagementBaseObject e = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();

detail = new string[]
{
  ((e["TargetInstance"])["Caption"]).ToString(),
  ((e["TargetInstance"])["ProcessID"]).ToString(),
  ((e["TargetInstance"])["SessionId"]).ToString()
};
```

I got 3 of 5, but how can I get:

- Window Title
- Process Id (Parent)

Hint: You might be able to use the Process Id to find the missing fields.

Comment: Linking the similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586870/detect-the-win-gui-process-that-starts-in-windows-using-cmanagementeventwatche

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: He's trying to obtain the *"Window Title"* and *"Parent Process Id"*.

Comment: @JohnB I'm aware of that, that is clearly stated in the question. What I meant was, WHY does the OP need those fields, and what problem is the OP having in getting them? The OP can enumerate the `e.Properties` and `e["TargetInstance"].Properties` collections to find out what values are actually available.  Assuming the `TargetInstance` is a [`Win32_Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process), it has `Caption`, `ProcessId`, and `ParentProcessId` properties...

Comment: @JohnB ... though the `Caption` may be empty at the time the process is created, since a UI may not have been created yet. The Win32 [`EnumWindows()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) and [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) functions can be used to find windows that belong to a given process ID, and then [`GetWindowText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) can get the title/caption of those windows.